# CUDA __syncthreads() and recursion

Tags: recursion, cuda

I want to use __syncthreads() to a recursion like

```
__device__ void foo(int k) {
  if (some_condition) {
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++) { 
       foo(i+k); // foo might take longer with some inputs
       __syncthreads();
    }
  }
}
```

How does this __syncthreads() now apply? I know it is only applied within a block. As far as I understand it, this holds for all local threads independently of the recursion depth? But what if I wanted to make sure that this __syncthreads() to a certain recursion depths? Is that even possible? I could check for the recursion depth, but I believe that won't work either.

Are there possible alternatives?

I've seen the that there are 3 syncthread extensions for CUDA Device >= 2.0

```
int __syncthreads_count(int predicate);
int __syncthreads_and(int predicate);
int __syncthreads_or(int predicate);
```

But I don't think they will help since they seem like an atomic counter.

Comment: I don't have exactly an answer as I never did something like that myself but just to check if you are aware, the some_condition you put in your code must evaluate the same for all the threads in the same block or it will deadlock.

Comment: Yes, that's what I fear as well.

Comment: Please can you clarify your question? I don't really understand what you are asking here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you know, `__syncthreads()` is only safe where all threads within a block reach the barrier. This means that if you are calling `__syncthreads()` from within a condition the condition must evaluate to the same on all threads within a block.

For `__syncthreads()` within recursion, this means that all threads within a block must execute the recursion to the same depth, otherwise not all threads will be reaching the same barrier.

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense, but I can imagine, that since recursion requires a fermi GPU, it doesn't matter on the recursion depth, just in the place in the code. It probably can have a look at the stack depth, yes but why, this would introduce a ton of potential problems (like deadlocks). I was trying to find further information on this. Is this defined somewhere? The easy and most probable solution for this is: **just don't use it in a recursion**

Comment: I would put it more strongly: don't use recursion in CUDA unless you have to.  EVERY thread has to maintain its own stack, resulting in a lot of extra off-chip memory accesses that would not be required if you can replace the recursion with iteration.  If you can't, then you might be able to maintain a simpler stack in shared memory.  Or you might be able to maintain the top few levels of the stack in shared memory or registers, reducing the total off-chip accesses (commonly used in GPU ray tracing).  As for syncthreads(), it's safe to use in any non-divergent code, recursion or otherwise.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarification on this. I thought that the cuda stack was maybe more efficient that a poorly selfmade one. Since I don't have had much exposure to cuda before this was the easiest way to express it. I'm currently doing a rewrite of said code anyway (recursionless and stackless), but I'm really interested in the __syncthreads behaviour in a recursion. Because I had this code running with __syncthreads() enabled and it worked and surprisingly didn't deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there possible alternatives?

Yes, don't use the recursion paradigm to express your function logic

Answer (score 0):

Off course what you said about __syncthreads() is true, it only works for local threads within the blocks therefore you have no control what is happening in other blocks. the best way for reduction is first make a reduction for the whole array which will general an array equal to the size of blocks. Then do not copy the array back to the Host instead call another reduction which will will have 1 block and threads similar to the number of blocks in the previous call and later copy the array of size 1 from Device to Host. but make sure to use cudaThreadSynchronize() between two calls coz unless the first reduction is generated you can make this reduction. this is two step reduction but it works for me.

cheers!!!
saif